# Modify Teamsite to Publishing Site (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, modern-experience

We got a public Team in "Microsoft Teams" for Information Technology to provide communication and provide News to our users. Every Team gets a SharePoint Online "Modern Teamsite" created automatically by default.

Now we are planning to create a SharePoint Online "Modern Publishing Site" for marketing purposes ("who we are" and stuff).

**Instead of having two sites, is it possible to convert the Teamsite created by Microsoft Teams to a Publishing Site (being able to stick it to a Hub Site)?**

Answer (score 0):

You should activate following features to convert the team site to publishing site:

1. SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure (site collection scope)
2. SharePoint Server Publishing (web scope)

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. Your answer fits for SharePoint Classic (on premise mainly) Sites to enable Publishing for a Teamsite. BUT: "Microsoft Teams" creates "Modern Teamsites" (Office 365 Groups based) in SharePoint Online. They cannot be converted to a "Modern Publishing Site"  by activating the publishing infrastructure.